# Wpf : Access to DataTemplate elements

Tags: wpf

In CustomControl, I used ControlTemplate / ItemsControl / ItemTemplate / DataTemplate / DataGrid.

I want to access the DataGrid. but It is not possible.
I need someone's help.

[Here is small test project.](https://github.com/bidasknakayama/MultiDataGrid)
I want to add "Sorting event" on the DataGrids.

4 datagrid is generated by ItemControl.

[image]

Here is visualtree by Live Visual Tree.

[image]

Of course, I tried to get the "DataGrid" by Visual Tree.
but It does not success. because "ContentPresenter" has no child tree.
it return 0 count. then All tried to getChild failed.

Is there a good way to get UI-element inside of dataTemplate ?

Comment: From where are you trying to get a reference to the DataGrid?

Comment: This is a Custom control. then I want to access from "MultiDataGrid.cs".  This code generated a ItemsSource for 4 x DataGrid.   The code "MultiDataGrid.cs" has "OnApplyTemplate". If I can add a event "Sorting" on the 4 dataGrid here, it's good. but Other parts is ok if it is inside of CustomControl logic. Thank you for comment  : )

Comment: There are no DataGrids created until you have set the ItemsSource of the ItemsControl. Where are you doing this?

Comment: I see.. I also tried to find DataGrid after setting of ItemsSource. but Result was same. I could not catch DataGrid in end of OnDisplayChanged. I also tried to find inside of  ItemsControl.Loaded or ItemsControl.SourceUpdated too.

Comment: Instead of trying to get a reference to the DataGrid, can't you replace the DataGrid elements in the ItemTemplate with a custom DataGrid type that already has whatever functionality that your are trying to add?

Comment: if we replace , but We again need to get the reference. We have to get reference with the datagrids. Replacement would not resolve.  Could you try to get reference in my code ?